# Snowflake data share between accounts in different regions

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I wanted to confirm my understanding on this. I have documented below my understanding on data share

> I think direct data share works only if the two snowflake accounts are
> in the same region of the cloud provider (for example US-EAST-1 of
> AWS). If I need to do a data share between two snowflake accounts in
> different regions of the cloud provider or in different cloud
> providers(AWS and AZURE), I will first need to setup a database
> replication and then create a share from the replicated database.

It will be a great help, if you can please let me know if my understanding is correct

Answer (score 0):

This is covered in the documentation [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-sharing-product-offerings.html#options-for-sharing). The table shows what is, and is not, possible with a Direct Share

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your understanding is correct. Secure data sharing works only if the two Snowflake accounts are in the same region of the cloud provider.

To share data between two snowflake accounts in different regions of the cloud provider or different cloud providers(AWS and AZURE), you will first need to set up a database replication and then create a share from the replicated database.

The other option is to make use of Snowflake Listings. A listing is an enhanced method of Secure Data Sharing and uses the same provider and consumer model.

Reference: https://other-docs.snowflake.com/en/collaboration/collaboration-listings-about